# help in find complexity of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

i try to find the complexity of this algorithm:

```
m=0;
i=1;
while (i<=n)
{
   i=i*2;
   for (j=1;j<=(long int)(log10(i)/log10(2));j++)
     for (k=1;k<=j;k++)
          m++;
}
```

I think it is O(log(n)*log(log(n))*log(log(n))):

- The 'i' loop runs until i=log(n)
- the 'j' loop runs until log(i) means log(log(n))
- the 'k' loop runs until k=j --> k=log(i) --> k=log(log(n))

therefore O(log(n)*log(log(n))*log(log(n))).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity is Theta(log(n)^3).

Let T = floor(log_2(n)). Your code can be rewritten as:

```
  int m = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= T; i++)
   for (int j = 1; j <= i+1; j++)
    for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++)
     m++;
```

Which is obviously Theta(T^3).

**Edit**: Here's an intermediate step for rewriting your code.  Let a = log_2(i).  a is always an integer because i is a power of 2.  Then your code is clearly equivalent to:

```
m=0;
a=0;
while (a<=log_2(n))
{
   a+=1;
   for (j=1;j<=a;j++)
     for (k=1;k<=j;k++)
          m++;
}
```

The other changes I did were naming floor(log_2(n)) as T, a as i, and using a for loop instead of a while.

Hope it's clear now.

Comment: More specifically, I think the value of m as a function of T would be:

m(T) = choose(T+2, 3) + (T+1)*(T+2)/2

Comment: Simplifying, it results in: m(T) = (T+1)(T+2)(T+3)/6

Comment: thank you very much, your explination is very clear.
m(n) is a logaritm graph, but i didnt understood why m(T) = choose(T+2, 3) + (T+1)*(T+2)/2 –

Comment: We want to count the number of triples (i, j, k) obtained by the loop indexes.

Let's first count the triples with j less than or equal i (and not equal to i+1), i.e. triples (i, j, k) satisfying 1 <= k <= j <= i <= T. This is exactly choose(T + 3 - 1, 3), the number of combinations with repetition of 3 elements out of T.  You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition.

Comment: Now consider the triples with j equal to i+1, i.e. triples (i, i+1, k).  For each i, from 0 to T, there are i+1 values for k.  Hence, there are 1 + 2 + ... + (T+1) triples of this kind. This is the T+1 Triangular Number, i.e. (T+1)(T+2)/2.  More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: but did you considered that j is until log(i) and not until i?

Comment: Yes, but I changed your code for something equivalent.  The i in my code is log(i) in your code.  If you can't see the equivalence, try running both and compare the value of m.

Comment: your code has the same m results, your informationn was very helpfull and usefull, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework?

Some hints:

I'm not sure if the code is doing what it should be. log10 returns a float value and the cast to (long int) will probably cut of .9999999999. I don't think that this is intended. The line should maybe look like that:

```
for (j=1;j<=(long int)(log10(i)/log10(2)+0.5);j++)
```

In that case you can rewrite this as:

```
m=0;
for (i=1, a=1; i<=n; i=i*2, a++)
    for (j=1; j<=a; j++)
        for (k=1; k<=j; k++)
            m++;
```

Therefore your complexity assumption for the 'j'- and 'k'-loop is wrong.
(the outer loop runs log n times, but i is increasing until n, not log n)

Comment: but j is until log(i) not i itself

Comment: Yes, but the value of `i` doubles in every loop. So in the last loop `i` == `n` (not `i` == `log n`). `a` is `log (i+1)`.